# C# Viewmodel to model

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I want to check if i'm doing things right.

So I'm trying to create an API in .net core.

So this is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateAdministrator([FromBody]AdministratorViewModel administrator){

    _unitOfWork.Administrators.Add(new Administrator
    {
       FirstName = administrator.FirstName,
       LastName = administrator.LastName,
       EmailAddress = administrator.EmailAddress,
       Password = administrator.Password,
       ManageAdministrators = administrator.ManageAdministrators
       });
       _unitOfWork.Complete();
    }
```

So I have the `AdministratorViewModel` as the object that contains the input the user does.
Then I pass the information to the `Administrator` object to create a new administrator.

Is there a better way then just write all the time 
`property = administrator.property`. So if for example I add an extra field `DateOfBirth` I have to add that on 3 different  locations (viewmodel, model and controller.

Is there a way to just fill or 'merge' the properties of 2 objects so it autofills all filled in properties?

Or should I do this in a different way?

Comment: Hi, you can use AutoMapper

Comment: Unfortunately this is asking for what people think is the right solution. There is no single solution to this, as there are multiple schools of thoughts. There are those that promote AutoMapper, and those that don't.

Comment: In general, you really **don't** want this to work automatically, without any control. Suppose for some reason there's a field in your `Administrator` model called `IsAdmin`. And suppose you bind all properties. Adding this to the posted view model by an attacker would cause so called **over-posting**. Regardless then of what actual way of avoiding code duplication you choose, please take care of this possible threat.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I tried overposting the api with `IsAdmin` but when values are being bind to the `AdministratorViewModel` (which does not contain `IsAdmin`) the value is ignored as it cannot bind to anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use automapper for that https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/

Another approach  you could create separate method like

```
Administrator  ModelFromView (AdministratorViewModel viewModel) 
{
//mapping code
}
```

But you have to add new mapped property to this method each time  when you add new property to your class in this way. Automapper allows to avoid it. But sometimes you need more control for your mapping process and second approach might help you with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a **copy constructor** for your class `AdministratorViewModel` and handle all the business logic there.

Afterwards you can just use:

```
_unitOfWork.Administrators.Add(new Administrator(administrator));
```

With this way you wouldn't have to add properties everywhere, when you later on decide to add more properties.

Answer (score 0):

Not always the best approach to use AutoMapper. Interesting read [here](https://cezarypiatek.github.io/post/why-i-dont-use-automapper/).

Comment: the main reason to avoid using AutoMapper is security. Automapper maps all properties from client model event if user can not set them from UI. but it is already  different story,

Answer (score 0):

Automapper is what you need

I used it in my production environment